# Javascript time bidding

Tags: javascript, jquery, timing

I want to make function that will alert('a') after 1s. But if during that 1s, this function will be called again, time counting will be reset.

like

```
bid();
//wait 500ms
bid();
//wait 300ms
bid();
//wait 1000ms
//now would be alert('a')
```

I've tried:

```
$.holdTime = function(key,time)
{
    var time = time ? time : 500;

    if (!$.isArray($.mmTimeHold)) {
        $.mmTimeHold = new Array();
    }

    var isHold = $.mmTimeHold[key];

    $.mmTimeHold[key] = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mmTimeHold[key]=false;
    },time);

    isHold = isHold === undefined ? false : isHold;
    return isHold;
};

$.isHold = function(key)
{   
    if (!$.isArray($.mmTimeHold)) {
        $.mmTimeHold = new Array();
    }   
    var isHold = $.mmTimeHold[key]; 
    isHold = isHold === undefined ? false : isHold;
    return isHold;
}
```

but Its not working as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for...

```
var timer = null;
function startBid(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(bid, 1000);
}
```